# Replaced Nested Object Value with separate Object with a different structure

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested, iteration, javascript-objects

I have an object of NBA Team names structured like so:

```js
const HomeAndAwayTeams =
{
  teams: {
    '0': { hTeam: 'San Antonio', AwTeam: 'New Orleans' },
    '2': { hTeam: 'Sacramento', AwTeam: 'Orlando' 
},
    '4': { hTeam: 'Indiana', AwTeam: 'Toronto' }, 
    '6': { hTeam: 'Chicago', AwTeam: 'Cleveland' },
    '8': { hTeam: 'Brooklyn', AwTeam: 'Miami' },  
    '10': { hTeam: 'Milwaukee', AwTeam: 'Memphis' 
},
    '12': { hTeam: 'Oklahoma City', AwTeam: 'Denver' },
    '14': { hTeam: 'Houston', AwTeam: 'Portland' }  }
}
```

I'm looking to replace the City Names with their respective Team Nicknames.

I have an object setup that has their nicknames as the values, and the city names as the keys.

```js
              const NBATeamsNickNames = {
                  "Atlanta": "Hawks",
                  "Boston": "Celtics",
                  "Brooklyn": "Nets",
                  "Charlotte": "Hornets",
                  "Chicago": "Bulls",
                  "Cleveland": "Cavaliers",
                  "Dallas": "Mavericks",
                  "Denver": "Nuggets",
                  "Detroit": "Pistons",
                  "Golden State": "Warriors",
                  "Houston": "Rockets",
                  "Indiana": "Pacers",
                  "LA": "Clippers",
                  "Los Angeles": "Lakers",
                  "Memphis": "Grizzlies",
                  "Miami": "Heat",
                  "Milwaukee": "Bucks",
                  "Minnesota": "Timberwolves",
                  "New Orleans": "Pelicans",
                  "New York": "Knicks",
                  "Oklahoma City": "Thunder",
                  "Orlando": "Magic",
                  "Philadelphia": "76ers",
                  "Phoenix": "Suns",
                  "Portland": "Trailblazers",
                  "Sacramento": "Kings",
                  "San Antonio": "Spurs",
                  "Toronto": "Raptors",
                  "Utah": "Jazz",
                  "Washington": "Wizards"                     
              }
```

I've tried several ways to replace the values, but I can't figure out how to access it if it was nested.

For example, I've tried something like this:

```js
for (const key in NBATeamsNickNames) if (key in HomeAndAwayTeams) HomeAndAwayTeams = NBATeamsNickNames[key];
```

Which of course, only works if the object values in HomeAndAwayTeams weren't nested, and at base level.

I've attempted some other methods like a for loop, and a map, but I'm inexperienced in iterating over objects, especially in this format, and I'm trying to understand the ***concept*** behind accessing data in this way **and replacing** it in this case.

**The number of teams in the HomeAndAwayTeams will change every day, it won't be a static amount. And of course, the teams within the object will change every day as well.**

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you don't need to iterate over `HomeAndAwayTeams` object, you need to iterate over `HomeAndAwayTeams.teams`. You can use [Object.keys](https://I%20guess%20you%20don%27t%20need%20to%20iterate%20over%20%60HomeAndAwayTeams%60%20object,%20you%20need%20to%20iterate%20over%20%60HomeAndAwayTeams.teams%60.%20You%20can%20use%20%5BObject.keys%5D%5B1%5D%20methot%20to%20do%20it.%20%20This%20will%20change%20your%20object%20in%20place.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20%7B%20teams%20%7D%20=%20HomeAndAwayTeams%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(const%20key%20of%20Object.keys(teams))%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(teams%5Bkey%5D.hTeam%20in%20NBATeamsNickNames)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teams%5Bkey%5D.hTeam%20=%20NBATeamsNickNames%5Bteams%5Bkey%5D.hTeam%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(teams%5Bkey%5D.AwTeam%20in%20NBATeamsNickNames)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20teams%5Bkey%5D.AwTeam%20=%20NBATeamsNickNames%5Bteams%5Bkey%5D.AwTeam%5D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method to do it.

This will change your object in place.

```
const { teams } = HomeAndAwayTeams
      
for (const key of Object.keys(teams)) {
  if (teams[key].hTeam in NBATeamsNickNames) {
    teams[key].hTeam = NBATeamsNickNames[teams[key].hTeam]
  }
  
  if (teams[key].AwTeam in NBATeamsNickNames) {
    teams[key].AwTeam = NBATeamsNickNames[teams[key].AwTeam]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I'm trying to learn the terms so I can read and learn more on this. So, I have a bit of a noob question: Is the { teams } portion a form of destructuring, or an object literal? I've been using JS for years, but just past couple years I have been pushing myself to take programming seriously.

Comment: Yes, it's destructuring assignment. In this case 'teams' and 'HomeAndAwayTeams.teams' refer to the same object. I've used it just to make code cleaner.